# How to delete given element from a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am practicing python and doing an exercise where I have to ask for input of different information from patients of a hospital (name, last name, etc) this information has to be saved in a different json file. I managed to do it however I also have to make it so, with an input, I can remove/edit a specific patient from the dictionary (along with all of their info) while keeping the others intact.
I was thinking that maybe I could assign a number to every patient that's added, so this patient can be tracked with the number, however I'm not sure how to code that. I did however made a function to clear everything from the json file, but it has to remove/edit someone specific, not everyone.

My code so far is:

```
import json

def read_file(file_name):
    obj_arch = open(file_name, 'rt', encoding='utf-8')
    
    str_contenido = obj_arch.read()
    res = json.loads(str_contenido)
    
    obj_arch.close()
    
    return res


def save_file(file_name, lista):
    obj_arch = open(file_name, 'wt', encoding='utf-8')
    
    str_content_to_save = json.dumps(lista)
    print(str_content_to_save)
    obj_arch.write(str_content_to_save)
    
    obj_arch.close()    

opcion = int(input("choose an option: 1 - read. 2 - save"))

if opcion == 1:
    lista = read_file('prueba_json.json')

    print("Full list:")
    print(lista)

else:
    lista = read_file('prueba_json.json')


    while True:
        print("--- PATIENT INFO ---")
        Name = input("Input name: ")
        Lastname = input("Input lastname: ")
        DateB= input("Input date of birht: ")
        repeat = input("Do you want to add more info?: ")
        clean_file = input("Clean everything from the json file? (yes/no): ")

       
        lista.append({
            "Name": Name,
            "Lastname": Lastname,
            "Date of Birth": DateB

            })

        if repeat == 'no' or repeat == 'NO':
            break

save_file('prueba_json.json',lista)
```

With this I was able to sabe the patients info in the json file, but how can I write another input like "Insert number of patient to remove or delete" to do that?
In order to clean the whole json file I've done it with this:

```
def clean_json():
    with open('prueba_json.json', 'w') as arc:
        arc.writelines(["[{}]"])

if clean_file == "yes" or clean_file == "YES":
    clean_json()
```

Maybe I could adapt some of this to remove or delete someone instead of the whole file?

Comment: You delete a single element from a dictionary using the `del` statement.  However, it sounds like what you really need here is a database.  You might look at sqlite3, which ships with Python.  And by the way, in `clean_json`, all you need is `arc.write('[]\n')`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to think about the problem logically, and ask a *clear, specific* question. We can't design program features for you."I was thinking that maybe I could assign a number to every patient that's added, so this patient can be tracked with the number" Well, **what does the data look like**? What is the **rule that will tell you** which patient to remove? And - what do you actually know about working with dictionaries? For example, do you know *any way at all* to remove part of the dictionary?

Comment: Sinc you are "doing an exercise" - *what does the exercise specification tell you* about how this is supposed to work? Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822 and [mre]. It is not interesting to us how you read and write the data file, because that part of the program is (apparently) already working. Since you are asking a question about *how to manipulate the data*, the interesting things for us are: 1) *what is the structure* of the existing data? 2) *what are the rules* for the manipulation?